# RedirectToAction is very slow in Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Using `RedirectToAction` works fine in Google Chrome, but when I test it in Internet Explorer it is working very slow.

```
public ActionResult DeleteAction(int id)
{
    return RedirectToAction("GetRecords", new { ClientId = ClientId });
}
```

Comment: Which IE version used? And how much time spent to load the `GetRecords` page?

Comment: IE 11 `GetRecords` Take  1 Min , in chrome its will take only 2 second.@TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: IE has issues. It already had lots of guys to begin with. So don't count on performance issues on IE. See if it runs well on FF, and GC

Comment: IE is always slow, yes take longer time than other browser that's why Microsoft release Edge browser.

Comment: IE Is slow compared to chrome  But I don't understand  in backend coding Its Really depend on browser type.

Comment: IE is *NOT* slow compared to Chrome when it comes to simply calling a URL. It's slower when you run benchmarks. *Debug* and *profile* your application to find out what's wrong. Why do you think it's *IE* at fault, instead of the action?

Comment: @progrAmmar first, no. That's simply wrong. Especially when it comes to calling a URL. Second, it's the *developer's job* to write a page that *doesn't* require a specific browser. That's what polyfills are for. Not unless said developer wants to limit his potential customers

Comment: @Jay *profile* your code. Use Fiddler, Glimpse to find out what is going on. Hit F12 and use the developer tools. Check the Network tab. Don't *assume* it's the browser's fault. You may be loading a ton of polyfills. And no, IE doesn't take minutes to load a page.

Comment: @Jay btw, you don't provide the *javascript* code, or the code that actually performs the deletion. It's not possible to help this way. This question should be closed unless you provide a minival example that actually reproduces the delay

Answer (score -1):

Your issue maybe that it's sending a 302 in response to the AJAX
request, not an overall page request, so you need to look for that
header and redirect the entire page if it's found.

Try this instead:

```
return JSon({redirect = Url.Action("GetRecords", "", new { ClientId =ClientId})});
```

Comment: *What* works? *Why* is this a solution and why is it a *good* solution? (it isn't), This only works because it *assumes* the browser calls the controller through Javascript. This is a `JSONP` string. It would be a **LOT** better if the javascript code did the redirection

Comment: It also assumes that IE isn't slow after all, since it *is* the browser that redirects. At best, this will be *SLOWER* than a 302 simply because the browser has to receive and parse the response first, then perform the same redirection as a 302